# selected duplicado usando old() en select laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un formulario que se comparte para las vistas de create y edit, para ambos tengo que mostrar  "estados" dentro de un select para poder mostrarlas, esto lo hago con un foreach, mi problema es al editar cuando algun usuario comete algun error en algun campo, se pierde el estado que tenia seleccionado antes y vuelve a la que esta registrada en la base de datos, de esta forma estoy mostrando la correcta cuando corresponda y usando el old para cuando haya algun error.

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="status">Estado:</label>
            <select class="custom-select" name="status" >
                <option value="">Selecionar</option>
                <option value="disponible" {{ old('status') == 'disponible' ? 'selected' : ($product->status == 'disponible' ? 'selected' : '')}}>Disponible</option>
                <option value="no disponible" {{ old('status') == 'no disponible' ? 'selected' : ($product->status == 'no disponible' ? 'selected' : '')}}>No disponible</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

El Old funciona solo en el formulario de crear, inspeccione el elemento y cuando ocurre un error al editar ambos items del select tienen el "selected" marcado, hay alguna forma de usar el old en el select para que recupere el campo seleccionado despues de un error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar, te recomendaría cambiar tus condicionales a una manera más legible y corta como esta:

```
{{ old('status', $product->status) == 'disponible' ? 'selected' : '' }}
```

El helper [old()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-old) puede recibir un segundo parámetro que será un valor por default.

En segundo lugar, tus condicionales se prestan a que ambas condiciones se cumplan, por eso obtienes `selected` en ambas `<option>`.

Por ejemplo, si asumimos que estos son los valores que llegan al formulario:

```
old('status') = disponible
$product->status = no disponible.
```

1. Para tu primer `<option>`:

   ```
    old('status') == 'disponible' // Verdadero, obtienes 'selected' en el primero.
   ```
2. Para tu segundo `<option>`:

   ```
    old('status') == 'no disponible' // Falso, pasas a la siguiente condición.
    $product->status == 'no disponible' // Verdadero, obtienes 'selected' en el segundo.
   ```

Ahora bien si, en lugar de eso, usas el segundo parámetro del método `old()`, dicha condición extra no sería necesaria.

Comment: Muchas gracias! me funciono perfecto